# "I am alive" for Google Computing Server

Tags: linux, ssh, email, google-cloud

What would the best recommendations be to create some sort of "I am alive mechanism" for a google cloud computing instance running linux. I am certain there are many victims who forget to turn off their machines if they do not plan to leave it running. Such a mechanism would assist to prevent such mishaps.

A few ideas that come to mind:

- an auto email that is sent each X hours via the crontab.
- a script which commands the google server to shut down upon disconnection of an ssh connection

Are there any other solutions which exist?